# Asp.Net gridview rows space

Tags: html, asp.net, css, web-applications

I have a gridview with only a templatefield, and I want that rows have a distance of 5-10px.
I try margin on item-style-css but not works. 
Only thing that seems modify the distance is the border, but I need the border for hoover effect, this is css ot template field item-style :

```
.event_home
{
    border: double;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #581017;
    background-image:url('../images/t_off.png');

   cursor:pointer;
}


.event_home:hover
{
    border: double;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #C5CC19;

}
```

I show my example, each row of gridview have only one cell, I want that the rows are separated so that I can see the page background between two rows.
Fig. A is what I have now, Fig. B is what I want:

```
Fig A

+---+
| A | 
+---+
| B | 
+---+
| C | 
+---+

Fig.B                     

+---+
| A | 
+---+
          <-- this is margin of N pixel
+---+
| B | 
+---+

+---+
| C | 
+---+
```

Comment: I couldnt get your question. Please be clear

Comment: Try adding cellspacing in gridview
eg CellSpacing="20"

Answer (score 0):

Please Try cellspacing in gridview it might work

```
 eg  <asp:GridView  CellSpacing="20" ..
```